# React build not working in Internet Explorer (IE 11)

Tags: reactjs, gulp, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I am rendering a react component on the server (SSR). I build my JS files with `gulp` and `babel` and then I hydrate the react component on the client side.

Everything works fine, except for **IE11/9/..**.

Here is my babel configuration:

```js
gulp.task('js-react', function() {
    const b = browserify({
        entries: [
            'node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js',
            'node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.production.min.js',
            'node_modules/react-dom/server.node.js',
            'js/shared/react/index.js'
        ],
        debug: true
    });

    return b
        .add(require.resolve('@babel/polyfill'))
        .transform(babelify())
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('react-client-side.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.path-to-file'));
});
```

Here is my index.js that is server to the client:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent';

global.hydrator = (props = {}) => {
    ReactDOM.hydrate(<MyComponent {...props}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
};
```

And my babel configuration (.babelrc):

```js
{
    "sourceType": "unambiguous",
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        ["@babel/preset-react", {
            "runtime": "automatic"
        }]
    ],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"]
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the error in IE?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I get  "SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught" because usage of spread operator like {...x}  and "SCRIPT5007: Object expected" for jquery.min.js